# Mysql query show people older than certain age

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a query to only show people who are older than 50 years of age, but i am having difficulty as I only have DOB and not an age field.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you save the DOB in `date` or `datetime` datatype you can use **[timestampdiff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)** as

```
select * from table_name
where  timestampdiff(year,dob,curdate()) > 50
```

Here is a test case

```
mysql> select timestampdiff(year,'1960-01-20',curdate()) as age ;
+------+
| age  |
+------+
|   55 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select timestampdiff(year,'1950-01-20',curdate()) as age ;
+------+
| age  |
+------+
|   65 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `dob` column Datatype is `DateTime`

```
SELECT *
FROM tblname
where YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(dob) > 55
```

[DEMO SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e916a/1)